# проблема с модулем logging

Tags: python

```
Проблему я решил вот так там где os.getenv('HOMEPATH'), \
                                 'test.log) я просто отступил 4 пробела в каждой строке и всё заработало. 
import os, platform, logging
            
            if platform.platform().startswith('Windows'):
                logging_file = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOMEDRIVE'), \
                    os.getenv('HOMEPATH'), \
                    'test.log')
                
            else:
                logging_file = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'), 'test.log')
            
            print('Сохраняем лог в', logging_file)
            
            logging.basicConfig(
                level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='%(asсtime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s',
                filename = logging_file,
                filemode = 'w')
            
            logging.debug('Начало программы')
            logging.info('Какие-то действия')
            logging.warning('Программа умирает')
```

сама ошибка --> Сохраняем лог в C:\Users\User\test.log
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 440, in format
return self.*format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 436, in _format
return self._fmt % values
KeyError: 'asсtime'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 1100, in emit
msg = self.format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 943, in format
return fmt.format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 681, in format
s = self.formatMessage(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 650, in formatMessage
return self.*style.format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 442, in format
raise ValueError('Formatting field not found in record: %s' % e)
ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'asсtime'
Call stack:
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\less.py", line 19, in 
logging.debug('Начало программы')
Message: 'Начало программы'
Arguments: ()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 440, in format
return self.*format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 436, in _format
return self._fmt % values
KeyError: 'asсtime'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 1100, in emit
msg = self.format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 943, in format
return fmt.format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 681, in format
s = self.formatMessage(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 650, in formatMessage
return self.*style.format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 442, in format
raise ValueError('Formatting field not found in record: %s' % e)
ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'asсtime'
Call stack:
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\less.py", line 20, in 
logging.info('Какие-то действия')
Message: 'Какие-то действия'
Arguments: ()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 440, in format
return self.*format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 436, in _format
return self._fmt % values
KeyError: 'asсtime'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 1100, in emit
msg = self.format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 943, in format
return fmt.format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 681, in format
s = self.formatMessage(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init*_.py", line 650, in formatMessage
return self.*style.format(record)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 442, in format
raise ValueError('Formatting field not found in record: %s' % e)
ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'asсtime'
Call stack:
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\less.py", line 21, in 
logging.warning('Программа умирает')
Message: 'Программа умирает'
Arguments: ()

Comment: У вас опечатка `astime`

Comment: спасибо сейчас исправлю